# How to Convert Datetime to Date in dd/MM/yyyy format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to write a query to get Date in dd/MM/yyyy format. (I do not want time).

So i wrote query like

```
SELECT  Convert(varchar,A.InsertDate,103) as Tran_Date
```

But when i write order by Tran_Date, it is giving me the result in wrong order.

Can some body please suggest what should i do.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Give a different alias

```
SELECT  Convert(varchar,A.InsertDate,103) as converted_Tran_Date from table as A
order by A.InsertDate
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use convert in order by as well:

```
SELECT  Convert(varchar,A.InsertDate,103) as Tran_Date
order by Convert(varchar,A.InsertDate,103)
```

Comment: add the `from table` part in your query